# Sort save with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core

I have two class Parent and Child and I'm using Entity Framework Core with database Oracle

```
public partial class Parent()
{    
   public Parent()
   {
      Childs= new HashSet<Childs>();
   }    
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public ICollection<Child> Childs{ get; set; }
}

public Child()
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Parentid {get; set;}
   public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I have an API that returns a Parent object, similar to:

```
Parent p = new Parent{
   Name = "Parent",
   Childs = new List()<Child>
   {
      new Child{Name="Child1"},
      new Child{Name="Child2"}
   }
}
```

When I save with a transaction, not keep the data ordered and assign id=1 to Child2 and id=2 to Child1

```
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction()){
   // object parent
   _context.SaveChanges();
   transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, as `HashSet<T>` doesn't implement `IList<T>`, however, if you are using `HashSet<T>` be aware that it has no concept of order.

Comment: Database records have no order either. As long as the primary key (in this case the Id)  is unique, you *shouldn't* care what its value is. The only sort order is the only explicitly applied by the `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Sorry I have ICollection, not IList, the model is from a template. I need id in order to after recover data in order

Comment: BTW `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally. Adding an explicit transaction doesn't help and can actually cause scaleability problems

Comment: @manupi26 there is no order, unless you specify it with `ORDER BY`. None whatsoever.  The server is free to return the rows in any order it likes if that makes retrieval faster. Even if you use a clustered key to force a physical order, the server is free to retrieve the rows in a different order. If you want to *retrieve* those child records a certain way, add an ORDER BY clause when reading them. In this example, it looks like the names are in alphabetical order so you can use `ORDER BY Name`.

Comment: The problem not is when read data, the problem is when save because the order in the object previously is important, after I can order by another fields (only by id). So, I need save id in same order like object

Comment: Then add an extra field like `DisplayOrder`. The problem is *not* with saving or with EF- apart from the *bad practice* of trying to give the PK business meaning. Display order *is* a business concern. Don't use the primary key for this.  The *database itself* won't give you any ID order guarantee. It only has to generate unique incrementing IDs, it doesn't need to specify them in strict sequential order inside a transaction.

Comment: Since the server *doesn't* have to provide strictly incrementing IDs to a single transaction, it can perform a ton of optimisations like pre-generating ID batches, caching them, using different ID batches for different threads in a paralleled transaction, thus reducing the synchronisation overhead needed to ensure each row gets a unique ID.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the answers. I have a problem because the database is old and it has a lot of data and it is used by another applications. I'm limited by that

Comment: In that case you'll have to execute individual INSERTs explicitly. EF (specifically, the Oracle provider) will use a multi-row INSERT if it can, instead of individual INSERTs. The provider you use (which one?) may have an option to disable this, but I doubt it. INSERT order simply isn't a concern for EF or *any* ORM. You should probably execute individual INSERTs (using Dapper or even raw ADO.NET) if you want to control INSERTs to that level